How to retrieve the content of an ItemAttachment (message/rfc822) using Microsoft Graph SDK for Java?
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I am working on a Java project using Microsoft Graph SDK and I am encountering an issue while trying to retrieve the content of an attachment of type message/rfc822. I am able to get other attachments (like FileAttachment) without any issues, but I am struggling to load the content of ItemAttachment.
Here is a snippet of my code:
AttachmentCollectionPage attachments = graphClient.users(request.getUser())
                .messages(request.getId())
                .attachments()
                .buildRequest()
                .get();

for (Attachment attachment : attachments.getCurrentPage()) {
    if (attachment instanceof FileAttachment) {
        FileAttachment fileAttachment = (FileAttachment) attachment;
        byte[] contentBytes = fileAttachment.contentBytes;
        // Handle file content
    } else if (attachment instanceof ItemAttachment) {
        ItemAttachment itemAttachment = (ItemAttachment) attachment;
        // Handle item attachment
        // The item field is always null
    }
}

The ItemAttachment has the following properties:
item = null
contentType = "message/rfc822"
id = "some-id"

I have already looked at this post How to retrieve contents of an itemAttachment via the Microsoft Graph API, but I still don't understand how to achieve this using the SDK.
After further research, I found that to retrieve the content of an ItemAttachment, I need to append /$value to the URI.
However, I am not sure how to implement this using Microsoft Graph SDK for Java. I have not tried using customRequest because I am looking for a cleaner solution within the SDK itself.
Is there a more straightforward way to retrieve the content of an ItemAttachment using Microsoft Graph SDK for Java? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I struggled with this too and after a lot of searching and some experimentation came up with an answer that worked for me. I am (currently) using the MS Graph API V 6.14.0. It does use a ContentRequestBuilder but it is the only way I could find of doing it right now.
    if (att instanceof ItemAttachment) {
    String attId = att.getId();
    try {
        URI uri = mAppClient
        .users().byUserId(userId)
        .messages().byMessageId(mMessageId)
        .attachments().byAttachmentId(attId)
        .toGetRequestInformation().getUri();
        ContentRequestBuilder crb = new ContentRequestBuilder(uri.toString() + "/$value", mAppClient.getRequestAdapter());
        InputStream is = crb.get();
        if (is == null) {
            log.warn("Could not get attachment which is itself an email because there is no content");
        } else {
            // read input stream (to ByteArrayOutputStream then call toByteArray())
            // input seems to be read in chunks of 8192 bytes
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Could not get attachment which is itself an email because of:", e);
    }
}

The ContentRequestBuilder is com.microsoft.graph.users.item.messages.item.value.ContentRequestBuilder. mAppClient is a GraphServiceClient.
